# POST request is always empty - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, post, request

I am using PHP 8.0.7, Laravel 8.41.0 and new to Laravel. Building some simple APIs. No issues with GET APIs but having trouble with POST.

The $request object is always empty no matter what I did. It just returns [].

I am posting below data in Fiddler :

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json

{
"parent_id" : "1",
"process_no" : "20",
"process_name" : "Aux Electrical",
"level" : "4",
"priority_no" : "1"
}
```

I tried to dump $request contents in api.php to no avail.

```
Route::post('/processtree', function (Request $request){
    return $request->all();
});
```

I tried all sorts of different versions of reading $request object, again did not work. All I get is [].

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe reformat your json to a valid one (`:` instead of `=`) and without the line breaks

```
{"parent_id":"1","process_no":"20","process_name":"Aux Electrical","level":"4","priority_no":"1"}
```

Comment: It looks like $request->getcontent() solves the issue. It accepted "=". However I still cannot get anything with $request->all(), even with ":" in the JSON data.

Comment: @Ozguru `$request->getcontent()`  returns raw data, same as `php::input` (`file_get_contents("php://input")`) That confirms to you that the data is received but the format is not correct to be parsed automaticaly